# How To use for loop with executequeryasync to get list items from SharePoint list?

Tags: javascript, jsom

Below is my code .

I want to pass ID's in CAML query and get respective title.

```
totalID=[1,2,3];
function GetTitleIdea()
{  
   var promise = GetItemId();
   promise.done(function()
   {  
     for(var i=0;i<totalID.length;i++)  
     {   
         var contextIdeas = new SP.ClientContext();          
         var list = contextIdeas.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ideas');          
         var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();           
         caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value 
         Type='Integer'>"+totalID[i]+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");         
         var returnedItemsIdeas = list.getItems(caml);  
         contextIdeas.load(returnedItemsIdeas);      
         contextIdeas.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this,
         function()
         {
             var enumeratorIdeas = returnedItemsIdeas.getEnumerator();
             while (enumeratorIdeas.moveNext()) 
             {              
                  var listItemIdeas =enumeratorIdeas.get_current(); 
                  Title=listItemIdeas.get_item('Title');
                  console.log(Title);
             }

         }),
         Function.createDelegate(this,
         function (sender, args) 
         { 
              Console.log(err.message);
         }));

      }

   });

}
```

Comment: do you want to use JSOM only? There is a simpler solution via REST API

Comment: Any reason you don't use the IN operator in the CAML query? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625761.aspx

Comment: Yes I want to use JSOM only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you modify `returnedItemsIdeas` within a loop and then call `executeQueryAsync` - probably expecting `returnedItemsIdeas` to still have the same value when `executeQueryAsync` callbacks fire.
This is not how things work in JavaScript.

You have to "remember" all items that you load and iterate them when then loading is done. I have modified your code to reflect what i mean - but it is **not tested**:

```
function GetTitleIdea()
{  
   var promise = GetItemId(),
       returnedItemsIdeas = [],
       contextIdeas = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
       list = contextIdeas.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Ideas'),
       caml = new SP.CamlQuery(),
       i, ideaToLoad;
   promise.done(function()
   {  
     for(i=0;i<totalID.length;i++)  
     {   
         caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value 
         Type='Integer'>"+totalID[i]+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");         
         ideaToLoad = list.getItems(caml);  
         contextIdeas.load(ideaToLoad); 
         returnedItemsIdeas.push(ideaToLoad);
     }       

     contextIdeas.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this,
     function()
     {
         var enumeratorIdeas,listItemIdeas, title;
         for(i=0; i<returnedItemsIdeas.length; i++)
         {
             enumeratorIdeas = returnedItemsIdeas[i].getEnumerator();
             while (enumeratorIdeas.moveNext()) 
             {              
                  listItemIdeas =enumeratorIdeas.get_current(); 
                  title=listItemIdeas.get_item('Title');
                  console.log(title);
             }
         }

     }),
     Function.createDelegate(this,
     function (sender, args) 
     { 
          Console.log(err.message);
     }));



   });

}
```

Comment: Thank You for quick reply.I tried your method but i got error for contextIdeas.push. I got below error "contextIdeas.push is not a function"

Comment: Just a typo probably, you should push it to the returnedItemsIdeas array

Comment: @AndersAune: yes. I fixed that.

Comment: When I used above code I get following error. "a.get_$19_0 is not a function" Nothing will happen after that.Thank you

Comment: I have modifed `contextIdeas.load(ideaToLoad);` to `contextIdeas.load(ideaToLoad, "Title");` so that the title-field will be included in the loading and not only the item. Also I have modified `listItemIdeas.get_item('Title');` to `listItemIdeas.item('Title');` - I guess the latter was causing the problem.

Comment: Nils, You are right contextIdeas.load(ideaToLoad, "Title");  listItemIdeas.item('Title');  this cause issues i removed it and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Here we should use Recursion process.

Place the code in a function and pass the **array[index]** ( your required value) as parameter to that function.
In success method cal the same function with **Incremental index**, continue this until reach the index count to array length.

If you want continue even in fail case cal the method in Failure function.

Hope this helps you :)